# push to a private repository as contributors

Tags: git, push, pythonanywhere

I'm collaborating to a Django project whose database is hosted by PythonAnywhere. From this project, a private repository has been created on GitHub. I then got invitation to that repository as contributor.

I then logged to PythonAnywhere and tried to push using my GitHub credentials, but it didn't work as the image shows.

[image: Push test]

I read [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) that *remotes* should be added to let collaborators pull/push. I cloned the repository but I think this is not the way. I also tried to check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations) but frankly I'm a novice in that and I didn't solve my problem.

Here's the **question**: is there a way to set up a configuration such that each contributor can push to the repository with its own credentials, so to track who did what?

Comment: I'm confused. The image you shared appears to show a _successful_ push to Github. Can you explain in more detail what you expected that did not happen?

Comment: One thing: The credentials used to authenticate to be able to push on a remote have _no_ relation whatsoever with the authors/committers of revisions.

Comment: @DanLowe sure: I got a successful thing but *not* with the expected Author. Since I used my username and password for GitHub, I was expecting myself as author (*inspiralpatterns*) and not *percanecto*.

Comment: @Edmundo could you please elaborate a bit on them? I understood something like: *'you can use whatever username and password but eventually the Author will be always the one specified in the `.git/config` file`*. But I'm not completely sure.

Comment: @Edmundo and, if so, is it possible to add more than one option for authentication?

Comment: @MattiaPaterna "is there a way to set up a configuration such that each contributor can push to the repository with its own credentials, _so to track who did what?_". The problem is in the assumption that by asking people to authenticate, you will know who did what.... and that's not the case. You could push things into a remote branch that actually don't belong to you. What anyone did doesn't depend on authentication but on who ***committed*** what (and there's no need to authenticate for that).

Comment: @Edmundo makes perfectly sense, thanks for explanation. However, it turns out that using `git commit --author="Name <email>"` works in showing the committer but on Github the commit is registered as *committer with (authenticated user)*. That is, the total number of contributors does not change. I'll maybe write an answer below, even though it is not exactly what I was looking for.